# Aviso: Un valor numérico no bien formado encontrado

Tags: php, fpdf

tengo problemas para representar las fechas en la cabecera de mi PDF y me sale el siguiente aviso:

> Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered in C:\xampp\htdocs\facturador\reportes\Kardex_Inventario.php on line 19

La linea 19 es 'RESUMEN DE SALDOS Y MOVIMIENTOS ....'

```
    function Header()
    {
        if ($this->page == 1)
        {
             $meses = array("Enero","Febrero","Marzo","Abril","Mayo","Junio","Julio","Agosto",
            "Septiembre","Octubre","Noviembre","Diciembre");
            
             $mes = isset($_GET['mes']) ? $_GET['mes'] : '';
             $ano = substr($mes,3,4);
            $this->SetFont('Arial','B',15);
            $this->Cell(100);
            $this->Cell(105,10,'RESUMEN DE SALDOS Y MOVIMIENTOS DE PRODUCTOS DEL MES DE '.strtoupper($meses[date($mes)-1].' del '.$ano),0,0,'C');
            $this->Ln(20);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Si no se encuentra el mes en `$_GET` el valor es cadena vacía, intenta cambiándolo por `$mes = isset($_GET['mes']) ? $_GET['mes'] : 1;`, pero aún faltaría validar que esté entre 1 y 12. Además, no necesitas la función `date()`, accede directamente al arreglo meses con `strtoupper($meses[$mes - 1]`

Comment: Ya lo intente pero nada, el problema esta en "$meses[date($mes)-1]", si pongo solo "$mes" compila correctamente pero obtengo "11/21"

Comment: Efectivamente, porque no es necesaria la función `date()` y `$mes` tiene un valor numérico. Para obtener el nombre del mes usas solo `$meses[$mes - 1]`

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza el substr y no olvides la coma antes del **-1**:

```
.strtoupper($meses[substr(date($mes), -1)].' del '.$ano),0,0,'C');
```